# 'Improve this question' in Reopen Votes review queue should lead to an edit inside the queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing Reopen Votes, there are two ways to edit the question: the 'Edit and Reopen' button at the top right, and the 'Improve this question' button in the post notice:

> [image: Reopen Votes review queue item]

When choosing 'Edit and Reopen', you get the opportunity to edit the question in the review queue and upon submitting the edit, it will cast a reopen vote:

> [image: Editing a question from the Reopen Votes review queue]

However, clicking 'Improve this question' will make you leave the queue, submitting the edit (or clicking Cancel) will take you back to the Q&A page and you still have to review the question again.

> [image: Regular edit question page]

Can the behaviour of the 'Improve this question' button be changed so that it matches the 'Edit and Reopen' button? Or alternatively, hide it in the review queue?

Comment: Hi Glorfindel, I'll look into correcting this. Is this an issue occurring in the Close Votes queues as well?

Comment: Thanks @LisaPark! It's only an issue in the Reopen Votes queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here was that when displaying questions embedded within the review queue UX for closed questions, the action buttons included in the closed question post notices were also being displayed. These action buttons led directly to the edit pages for the posts in question, and when clicked from within a review queue, caused the user to leave the reviews workflow.

This has been fixed - the actions button in post notices for closed posts are now no longer displayed when the user is viewing the post embedded in a review queue screen.

---

> Maybe reopen?
> Edit button leads astray
> No more! Button gone!